# Returning an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I'm trying to learn C++ and had a question about returning arrays in C++. I know that in this case perhaps Vector may be better and that there is no need for a getter method as the fields are visible within the same class but I'm trying to learn about memory management so I'll use them.

```
class Color {
    double r;
    double g;
    double b;
    public:
    Color(int a, int aa, int aaa) {
        r = a;
        g = aa;
        b = aaa;
    }

    bool operator==(const Color &other) {
        double *otherCol = other.getter();
        return otherCol[0] == r && otherCol[1] == g && otherCol[2] == b;
    }

    double* getter() const {
        double second[3] = {r,g,b};
        return second;
    }
};

int main() {
    Color col1(23, 54, 200);
    Color col2(23, 54, 200);
    cout << (col1 == col2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code should print out a 1 if the RGB colors are the same and 0 otherwise. But it does not print a 1. To debug, I added the following lines (twice on purpose) right before the return statement in `operator==`:

```
cout << otherCol[0] << " " << otherCol[1] << " " << otherCol[2] << endl;
cout << otherCol[0] << " " << otherCol[1] << " " << otherCol[2] << endl;
```

Oddly enough, the results are different:

```
23 54 200
6.91368e-310 6.91368e-310 3.11046e-317
```

Can someone please tell me what causes this and what would be a reasonable remedy that does not rely on Vector or dynamic allocation of memory? Let's assume that we don't want to pass in an array into `getter()` to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getter` you are returning the address of a local variable which results in undefined behavior so you are getting random memory.  If you return a pointer you have to do something like `new` the variable in the called function and `delete` it after the function returns.

Or you could make `second` a class member which would keep it from going out of scope.

You could also pass the array in as a parameter.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that when a variable is returned from a function, a copy is made and returned so even when the function is out of scope, it works. Why is that not the case here? Is there a way to do this without dynamic memory alloc?

Comment: @Manbearpig A copy is made, but here it is a copy of the address of the local variable which goes out of scope at the end of the function so the memory location is invalid when the function returns.

Comment: So that only works for non-pointers? As in because the array is just a pointer to doubles, it does not work?

Comment: It works for primitive types like `int` and also works if you return a first class object (not a pointer) which will call the copy constructor of the returned class.  It never works with pointers to local variables.

Comment: I see, that's one good thing to learn. My first intuition was to just dynamically allocate memory for `second[]` in `getter()` or to declare the array in the calling function but someone had told me, after looking at my code, that the array can be returned by value. Thus, I was seeking other avenues. I guess not then?

Comment: @Manbearpig Your first intuition was correct :)